# Localhost:3000 says Project with name "<Name of iModel>" does not exist

Tags: imodeljs

I have the simple viewer app running on localhost. Once I have clicked on 'Open Sample iModel', I get message `localhost:3000 says Project with name "" does not exist`.   I believe its me not setting `imjs_test_imodel` and `imjs_test_project` correctly. I've tried a number of times trying different syntax and then rebuilding the app, only to get the same stumbling block. No doubt its me but any advice greatly appreciated. Extract of the lines I have edited within .env.local below:

`imjs_test_imodel="via-model"`

`imjs_test_project="via-model"`

Answer (score 0):

.env.local file variables dont require the quote marks around the names - try:

```
imjs_test_imodel=via-model
imjs_test_project=via-model
```